# Can't install Active Directory Management Gateway Service on Windows Server 2003 DC because hotfix 969166 is missing

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2003, .net, .net-3.5

I need to install the [Active Directory Management Gateway Service](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2852) on two Windows Server 2003 domain controllers, in order to be able to use the Active Directory PowerShell module on other computers in the environment; this is required as a workaround to not having more recent DCs in the domain, which is a condition that can't be solved at the moment.

However, the aforementioned package requires hotfix [KB969166](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/969166), which seems to not be available anywhere, not even upon request (as it is instead the case for the *other* required hotfix, [KB969429](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/969429)).

The download page states that "this hotfix will be eventually merged into the .NET Framework 4.0", but this doesn't appear to be a solution, because the 4.0 framework is actually installed on those domain controllers (as well as all available .NET updates), but I still get an error when installing ADMGS because that hotfix is missing.

I know we are out of support here; unfortunately, adding another DC to the environment is not an option. This notwithstanding, however, that package *should* still be usable, and the hotfixes it requires to be installed *should* be available.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You may be able to `Start` =>`Windows Update` ... it is easier than having to apply the hotfix yourself

Comment: Hotfixes are not distributed via Windows Update.

Comment: Just discovered that myself :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want it:

http://hotfixv4.microsoft.com/.NET%20Framework%203.5%20-%20Windows%202000,%20Windows%20Server%202003,%20Windows%20XP,%20Windows%20Vista,%20Windows%20Server%202008%20(MSI)/sp1/DevDiv758402/30729.4174/free/392858_intl_x64_zip.exe

I wouldn't be surprised if you have problems with the installation or have to stand on one leg while reciting some medieval chant to get everything working.

Comment: Worked flawlessly, thank you. Still wondering why MS doesn't allow it to be downloaded anymore (unless you already have the direct link); there's not even any comment such as "we removed this download"... it just isn't there.

Comment: If you know the kb number, it may be available using this link instead of the original kb article: http://hotfixv4.microsoft.com:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/hotfix/kbhotfix?kbnum=969166&kbln=en-us&wa=wsignin1.0  .  Reference: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mmcintyr/archive/2008/09/02/how-can-you-download-a-hotfix-without-contacting-microsoft.aspx

Comment: question? how do we know this is legit software? People can post any hyperlink they want on the blogs...

Comment: That "microsoft.com" URL seems legit. And no, not in the standard ironic "seems legit" sense.